# What is a better way to implement wp_get_archives modification without touching the wordpress core?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I started my first ever theme or any kind of development in Wordpress since yesterday for my blog, and after getting most of the basic stuff done, I was looking to create an Archive page. The default output for the archive page achieved through the wp_get_archives function is **the_title**(of the post).

However, I wanted to ***display*** the *archive posts* along with their ***respective post_date***. It seems that the format is hard-coded within the general_template.php (*really!! but I am new to WordPress design philosophy to further remark on that*)

I did that by directly modifying the ***general_template.php*** file in *wp-includes* directory. I changed the **wp_get_archives** & **get_archives_link** functions (main code changes are...)

```
*wp_get_archives() 
    ............
    $text = strip_tags( apply_filters( 'the_title', $result->post_title, $result->ID ) );
    $text .= "|||" . date('F j, Y', strtotime($result->post_date));

*get_archives_link() 
    ............
    elseif ('withdate_ms' == $format) {
        $text_pieces = explode("|||", $text);
        $link_html = "\t<li>$before<a href='$url'>{$text_pieces[0]}</a> &bull; {$text_pieces[1]} $after</li>\n";
    }
```

This achieved what I wanted to do. But, I am *NOT* feeling it is *good practice* by trying to directly change the core wordpress files (especially for something this trivial). I am new to WP, but I guess there must be a Wordpress-way of achieving this, for sure. **How would I go about implementing this modification without touching the core?** And will this approach work for other changes to core functionality (for any other set, if I need to change in future)?

Comment: You can always create your own function by copy-pasting the `wp_get_archives( )` into your theme's `functions.php` file and then renaming it and using that instead.

Comment: Do I need to wholly copy-paste wp_get_archives() and get_archives_link() and modify it (is name change necessary)? Also, does this guarantee that other helper functions (such as strip_tags) will be available within the environment? Is this the Wordpress-way-best-practice of doing it? Will this work for future update changes to the core functionality?

Comment: Yes. Copy the entire function, rename it to prevent naming conflicts, edit it to your needs, and use that function to get your results. All other functions in and around your new functions will work just fine.
If there are future core functionality updates to those two functions, you'll have to either leave your functions as is, or update them with the changes. They will not automatically update themselves.

Comment: Will try that one. Thank you :) but still, isn't there a way to just extend those two functions without the whole redundancy. that would certainly be a good thing.

Comment: Why don't you use a `filter` to modify the output? `add_filter('get_archives_link', [FUNCTION]);` REF : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/#Filters

Comment: @dscy-prsm It would be a good thing, but extending those functions is pretty much impossible because the few hooks that are there are in the wrong places and have the wrong arguments to be useful for your needs.

Comment: @JoeBuckle The few hooks that are in those functions have the final output string as their only arguments. If they had provided the `$post` value as an argument, it would be trivially easy to modify to the OP's needs, but as they are now, a new function would have to be created to grab the date from the database anyway, so why not just modify a clone of the function, instead of performing two hits on the DB to get the data.

Comment: @Benjam Looks like this is the easiest way that takes care of the update issue. Can you post it as answer, and I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy-paste the `wp_get_archives( )` function into your theme's `functions.php` file, then rename it (to avoid function name conflicts), and use that function as a drop-in replacement anywhere that you would normally use `wp_get_archives( )`.

Make sure to copy the entire function and all other functions that are used inside of that function should work just fine.

One thing to note, is that if there are any future updates to `wp_get_archives( )`, you'll have to either integrate those changes into your new function, or live without those changes, as the updates will have no effect on your function.